# Cannot read propery 'abort' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using `$.get` jquery function each time the user type in an input.
My function looks like this

```
function checkField(va) {
    $.get(
        '/admin-tool',
        {
            ctrl : 'checker',
            value : va
        },
        function(d) {
            if($('.answer',d).text() != '1') {
                $('.main h1').text('Something went wrong, Read the instructions carefuly');
            }
    });
}
```

I need to use the `abort()` function to prevent the previous calls to finish his xhr after the last one.

So I did

```
 var xhrcall;
 function checkField(va) {
  xhrcall.abort();
    xhrcall = $.get(
        [...]
    });
}
```

But I go the error

> Cannot read propery 'abort' of undefined

Of course it is not defined, but the ajax function doesn't even fire anymore.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Do you mean `abort()`?

Comment: Yes sorry typo! I edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've provided some comments to your code. Please check them.

```
var xhrcall; // no value assigned here and probably nowhere else -> undefined!

function checkField(va) {
  xhrcall.abort(); // so this line causes the error and I believe JS execution stops here!!
  xhrcall = $.get(
    [...]
  });
}
```

If you would like to exec `$.get` try this (basically, call abort() only if `xhrcall` has been initialized):

```
function checkField(va) {
  if (xhrcall)  { 
    xhrcall.abort(); 
  }
  xhrcall = $.get(
    [...]
  });
}
```

Happy Hacking :)